# Existence of weird complex norms

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices

Consider the matrix $$D=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&e^{i\theta}\end{pmatrix}.$$ For the commonly used norms $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ or for $\theta=0$ the associated subordinate norm is $1$. Is it always true ? can a subordinate norm be strictly bigger than one ?

Comment: If $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ denotes the usual norm on ${\bf C}^2$ and we pick an invertible $A\in {\rm GL}_2({\mathbb C})$ then we can define a new norm by $\Vert x\Vert_A = \Vert Ax\Vert_2$. I suspect, but have not checked, that "most" choices of $A$ will lead to examples where there exist $y\in {\bf C}^2$ such that $\Vert Dy\Vert_A > \Vert y\Vert$.

Comment: I just learned (from Wikipedia), that the subordinate norm is another word for operator norm. Which also explains the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ defined by $\Vert z \Vert^2 := |z_1|^2+|z_1+z_2|^2$. Then
$$\left\Vert \left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ -1 \end{array}\right) \right\Vert^2 = 1,$$
$$\left\Vert D\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ -1 \end{array}\right) \right\Vert^2 = \left\Vert \left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ -e^{i\theta} \end{array}\right) \right\Vert^2 = 1 + |1-e^{i\theta}|^2.$$
If $e^{i\theta} \ne 1$, we derive that the subordinate norm of $D$ is $>1$.