# Real and complex operator norms

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix and $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$. When we look at the operator norm of $A$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|$ we can either consider the inclusion of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ or the restriction of $\|\cdot\|$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Are these points of view equivalent?

In other words do we always have:
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}
$$
for $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I hoped that we could use as an intermediary step [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440771/existence-of-weird-complex-norms) however, I was a bit optimistic.

Comment: That doesn't sound plausible to me. For example, take $A=\textrm{diag}(1,2)$ and build a norm that gives small norm to $(1,i)$ and large norm to $(1,2i)$.

Comment: Yes, because you can reduce to diagonal matrices via the SVD, and the result is immediate for diagonal matrices.  *Edit:* Ah, I’d missed “a norm”.

Comment: @ChristianRemling indeed, thanks! for $\|(z_1,z_2)\|^2=|z_1|^2+|z_1+i z_2|^2$ and the proposed matrix, we have indeed $\|A\|_\mathbb{R}=2$ and $\|A\|_\mathbb{C}\geq2.25$. Do not hesitate to post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: The answer is positive if $\mathbb{C}^n$ is endowed with the canonical hermitian norm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}$No. E.g., let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\left\|\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2 \end{bmatrix}\right\|=|z_1|+|z_1+iz_2|.$$
Then the real norm of $A$ is $1$ and the complex norm of $A$ is $2$.

---

Indeed, if $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}\in\R^2$ with $x_1\ne0$, then
$$\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\frac{|x_1|+|x_1+0i|}{|x_1|+|x_1+ix_2|}
\le\frac{2|x_1|}{|x_1|+|x_1|}=1,$$
with $\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=1$ if $x_2=0$. So, the real norm of $A$ is $1$.

If now
$z=\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{bmatrix}\in\C^2$ with $z_1\ne0$, then
$$\frac{\|Az\|}{\|z\|}=\frac{2|z_1|}{|z_1|+|z_1+iz_2|}
\le2,$$
with $\frac{\|Az\|}{\|z\|}=2$ if $z_2=iz_1$. So, the complex norm of $A$ is $2$.

Answer (score 8):

What you can do is to reverse the question:

> Given a norm $\|\cdot\|$ over $\mathbb R^n$, does there exist a norm $N$ over $\mathbb C^n$, whose restriction to $\mathbb R^n$ is $\|\cdot\|$, and such that for every $M\in{\bf M}_n(\mathbb R)$, the subordinated norms coincide :
> $$N(M)=\|M\|\quad ?$$

Notice that we have obviously $N(M)\ge\|M\|$, a larger domain implying a larger upper bound. Thus only the reverse inequality is at stake.

This question was addressed in the Exercises 5 and 6, Chapter 7 of my book *Matrices* (Springer-Verlag GTM 216, 2nd edition). A solution is as follows.

Define $N$ by
$$\forall z\in\mathbb C^n,\quad N(z)=\inf\left\{\sum_\ell|\alpha_\ell|\|x^\ell\|;z=\sum_\ell\alpha_\ell x^\ell\right\},$$
where the decompositions obey to $\alpha_\ell\in\mathbb C$ and $x^\ell\in\mathbb R^n$. That $N\ge0$ is $\mathbb C$-homogeneous ($N(\mu z)=|\mu| N(z)$) and satisfies the triangle inequality are pretty obvious. If $z=u+iv$ with $u,v\in\mathbb R^n$, then any decomposition yields
$$u=\sum_\ell a_\ell x^\ell,\quad v=\sum_\ell b_\ell x^\ell$$
where $\alpha_\ell=a_\ell+ib_\ell$. We have
$$\|u\|\le\sum_\ell|a_\ell| \|x^\ell\|\le\sum_\ell|\alpha_\ell| \|x^\ell\|.$$
Taking the infimum over decompositions of $z$, this yields $\|u\|\le N(z)$. Likewise $\|v\|\le N(z)$. Thus $z\ne0$ implies $N(z)>0$. Thus $N$ is a norm over $\mathbb C^n$.
If $z\in\mathbb R^n$, then $u=z$ and (see above) $\|z\|\le N(z)$. Since the reverse inequality is obvious, we obtain that the restriction of $N$ to $\mathbb R^n$ is $\|\cdot\|$.

Given $z\in\mathbb C^n$, and $z=\sum_\ell\alpha_\ell x^\ell$ being a decomposition as above, we have the decomposition $Mz=\sum_\ell\alpha_\ell Mx^\ell$. Therefore
$$N(Mz)\le\sum_\ell|\alpha_\ell| \|Mx^\ell\|\le\|M\|\sum_\ell|\alpha_\ell| \|x^\ell\|.$$
Taking the infimum over all decompositions of $z$, we obtain $N(Mz)\le\|M\|N(z)$. Taking the supremum over $z$, this gives $N(M)\le\|M\|$, hence the equality.

Comment: I edited my answer, and fixed a logical mistake.